# Differences between combinations of real or complex numbers

Tags: matrices

Want to ask what's the difference between

$\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, \mathbb{R}^{2n}$?

I try to understand what's the difference, because for $\mathbb{R}^n$ you put vectors as coulums in a matrix.

Example for an $\mathbb{R}^2$ so as i understood is:

$\vec{a}^T= (1,2), \vec{b}^T=(3,4) \Rightarrow \underline{A} = \left( \begin{array}{c} 1&3 \\ 2&4 \end{array} \right)$

but for just an tuple of numbers i get that for A which is not a matrix:

$A = \{(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)\}$

I am a little bit confused what would be the rest of them and how to take the point of view for matrices. 
thx for any help to understand the differences. examples would be fine.

br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $n=3$,

We have $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ which is the Cartesian product of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

We have $\begin{bmatrix} 1  & 4 & 7\\ 2  & 5  & 8\\ 3 & 6 & 9\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$, not only it encodes the number of entries, it tells us the shape, that is the number of rows and columns.

and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\end{bmatrix}^T \in \mathbb{R}^6$.

Comment: @siong-they-goh hi. could i ask you something. just for the better interpretetion. with [ ] you mean an tupel or just an vector? and in example òne stands $\mathbb{R}$ for each element which is represented by 1, 2 or 3 to know that each number out of $\mathbb{R}$ could stands in that position?

Comment: hmm... what's your definition of tuple and vector? The square bracket is simply due to my habit, it can be replaced by round bracket. Yes, I just pick $1,2,3$ as a particular example, they can be replaced by other real number.

Comment: yeah thats the point. i try to understand it for myself exactly how is that defined for $\mathbb{R}$, set of numbers and tuple. So how i understood is $\mathbb{R}$ for the position how in your example  x=1 where $x \in \mathbb{R}, y \in \mathbb{R}, z \in \mathbb{R}$ in that point of view, because if you make an $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ as an tupel you got an pool of numbers as a pair like as that example for just the number zero $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} = \{ (-infty,0), (...,0),(0,0),(0,...),(0,+infty) \}$ but if i see how in the scripts vectors

Comment: are jused and just set together to a matrix i am wondering why that hasnt any affect also to the matrix at itself. i think but i am not sure, if that is not just an rule which is set. like an axiom. if it's just an axiom, ok i have just to learn it, but if not i have a logical problem to figure out why didnt has any effect to the matrx notation.

Comment: a set is a collection of objects (well, I am skipping some details here), it is not ordered, for example $\{1,2\} = \{2,1\}$. A tuple has an ordering $(1,2) \ne (2,1)$.  $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a set, of which each element is a tuple with $2$ real numbers. As for your doubt regarding matix notation, hmm.... I don't quite get your question. Remark: minor technical details, usually $-\infty \notin \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: i ment for your secound example. it could be seen as an $(1 2 3)^T \times (4 5 6)^T \times (7 8 9)^T$ to this matrix which represents $\mathbb{R^{3 \times 3}}$ but here ist nothing happens with each single object. just written as an normal known matrix notation. that i ment with probebly just an axiom. here doesn't happend that the objects are also combined as a normal set of numbers or a tuple are. for example A = {a,b} and B = {x,y} to $A \times B = \{ (a,x), (a,y), (b,x), (b,y) \}$ and that for each elements between each kind of a group or set of

Comment: numbers or whatever they are to represent the matrix notation

Comment: well, we can view $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ as isomorphism of $(\mathbb{R}^3)^3$, however, I think there are addition operations that are meant for matrices such as matrix multiplicaiton.

Comment: @siong-they-goth thx. i will search the new words ans try to understand it better.